# Toggle width of an image inside a gallery, when one is clicked the others are disabled

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a gallery with thumbnails images. When clicking on one thumbnail, its width will animate and show the full image. When re-clicking on it it will shrink back to its original size. I have achieved that with a toggle function and it works fine.

The problem is that when I click on a thumbnail I would like the other thumbnails to be disabled but I'm not able to achieve that. Is that possible?

Here is the HTML:

```
<figure class="grid_4 alpha medium"><img class="medium pl pt" src="images/gallery/1.jpg" /><span class="rollover opa2"></span></figure>
<figure class="grid_2 small"><img class="small pr pt" src="images/gallery/4.jpg" /><span class="rollover opa2"></span></figure>
<figure class="grid_4 omega medium"><img class="medium pr pt" src="images/gallery/5.jpg" /><span class="rollover opa2"></span></figure>
```

And this is the jquery:

```
$('.gallery figure').toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({width:620, height:620}, 500, "easeOutExpo");
},function(){
    $('.gallery .medium').animate({width:300, height:300}, 500, "easeOutExpo");
    $('.gallery .small').animate({width:140, height:140, marginTop:0}, 500, "easeOutExpo");
});
```

I'm not that great with jquery so if anyone can be of any help I would much appreciate.

Many thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than suppressing the toggle event (which adds overhead), I would suggest the use of a simple *flag* variable to determine whether or not an image is currently expanded to full size.

See the following demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/yWSBx/

```
var flag = false;

$('.foo').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('focus')) {
       ////////shrink image
    }
    else {
        if(!flag) {
            ////////expand image
            flag = true;
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Hi adamb, thank you for your help. I've used your code and I have now managed to disable the unexpanded images but once the first image is clicked and expanded, if clicked again it doesn't shrink back. [http://jsfiddle.net/2TPfn/] is the code I am using, could you spot what's wrong with it? It does work when clicked once (image expands) but it doesn't shrink back. I don't know why it doesn't work on fiddle but it does work locally. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: I have added an xtra else statement for the true flag and it works! A massive plus to your hint, you've been very helpful.

Comment: change this line: **$(this).find('img').animate({width:620, height:620}, 500, "easeOutExpo").addClass('focus');** to this: **$(this).addClass('focus').find('img').animate({width:620, height:620}, 500, "easeOutExpo");** What's happening is that **.find()** returns the selected 'img' element, not the original "this" element, so when you chain the **.addClass()** your actually adding the 'focus' class to the wrong element. Thus, **.hasClass()** will always return false. If correct please mark so :)